# By default, Excel should opened as readonly without showing readonly prompt

Tags: vbscript

I am creating an Excel file and saving the file as readonly using VBScript. When I manually open the file the read only prompt appears. I don't want that readonly prompt I just wants the file to be opened as readonly whenever any user opens the file manually.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a moment to read about [Asking a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then post some code that we can help you fix.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

```
excelfile = "Filename of your new excel goes here" 'Example: C:\Documents\TestExcel.xlsx"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
book.SaveAs(excelfile)
book.Close
objExcel.Quit

Set xf = objFSO.GetFile(excelfile)
If Not xf.Attributes AND 1 Then xf.Attributes = xf.Attributes + 1
MsgBox "Task Complete", vbOKOnly, "Create Read Only Excel"
```

It directly opens the Excel file as read only without any prompt.